# SVG or VectorDrawable runtime builder

Tags: java, android

I wish to build vector image in runtime, depending on user input, and then put it into ImageView as fast as possible.

I have tried VectorDrawable, but it's require to have xml before app starts and i didn't found legal way to use it in runtime.

So i am  looking for some android  built-in tools to build svg or VectorDrawable in runtime without creating file in storage. Does anybody have an ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, vectors cannot be created at runtime! There has to be a xml file for using vectors.